# Same Ajax called twice..JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a question in JQuery..I m using `$.ajax()` in my code `(Function 1)`to send the fieldname and the sequence number to the ctrller which gets its data by `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['sequenceno']` and updates the fieldname in the table with sequence no given..And generates the Preview Display Panel with the inserted fields ..
Now I'm  trying the change the field name again tat is Now when I click on the generated display panel fields, the corresponding settings will open and i will try to change the name of the field now`(Function 2)`

Both `Function1` and `Function2` are same ..In the `Function1` I'm sending the fieldname and the sequence no

In the Funciton 2,i want to send the same fieldname and (but the other value)sequenceno..

But in Function1 (sequenceno is the counter value)
Whereas in the Function2 (sequenceno is the clicked div id (display Panel))

How can i make use of the same func for both ..Or could i need to use separate funcs..

Even i tried with 2 separate funcs with different urls but not updated correctly

My code is

```
    //This is what i insert the field initially

              $(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").change(function (){
             fieldname=$(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").val();
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "./server",
        data: "name="+fieldname+"&sequenceno="+counter,

                success: function(msg){
                      }//success
           });//ajax

     });//change

//After inserting to get the updated values in JSON format

     var htm = $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
          url: "./viewforms",
         async: false
       }).responseText;
        var myObject = eval('(' + htm + ')');


    gettype=myObject.attributes[0]["type"];
   getlabel=myObject.attributes[0]["labels"];

    //showing in my DisplayPanel view

            $("#labelstr"+counter+"").html(getlabel);
     });//change
```

Now
    When i click the DisplayPanel view

```
      $("#displayPanel div").live("click", function(){
                             div_id=$(this).attr("id");

                                var htm = $.ajax({
                                  type: "GET",
                                  url: "./getattributes/"+div_id+"",
                                  async: false
                                 }).responseText;
                                var myObject = eval('(' + htm + ')');


                                gettype=myObject.attributes[0]["type"];
                                getlabel=myObject.attributes[0]["labels"];
                                getsize=myObject.attributes[0]["size"];

    if(gettype=='Text')
     {
    $(".TextFieldSettings").show(function(){
    $(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").val(getlabel);//showing the updated value
                             if(getsize=='100')
                           {
             $("#fieldSize option:contains(Small)").attr("selected",true);
                           }
                             else if(getsize=='200')
                            {
        $("#fieldSize option:contains(Medium)").attr("selected",true);
                         }
              else 
            {
          $("#fieldSize option:contains(Large)").attr("selected",true);
            }
//Again i m changing the fieldname


       $(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").change(function (){
      fieldname=$(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").val();


                                alert(div_id);
                                        $.ajax({
                                           type: "POST",
                                           url: "./editsettings",



                                                                         data: "name="+fieldname+"&sequenceno="+div_id,
                                           success: function(msg){

                                            }//success
                                           });//ajax


});//change in text value later*/



                    });//show
                    }//if type = TEXT

                });//displaypanel Div clicked
```

But now if I try to change the fieldname again I'm writing another POST function `editsettings` but the execution comes inside `Func1`(changing initially) instead of `Func2`(changing in the fieldname again)...
Please anyone get out the answer for this....
Note:
`$(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").change()` is used twice inside my prg ..May be because of this the updation goes wrong

Comment: Which part is actually the question here? Do you want to know if you can just have a single re-usable function vs two different functions?

Comment: Two different function () But both name is is like
$(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").change(function(){});

Same thing but different purpose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that both of your event handlers are firing, and you only want the latter one to fire.

The jQuery .change() function *adds* an event handler to the change event. It doesn't replace existing ones. If you want to remove the previous handler, you need something like:

```
$(".TextFieldSettings #fieldTitle").unbind('change')
```

before you attach a new handler.

please note that I'm not sure this works (I just found it from the api docs) and I can't test it right now. However, the general idea is that if you want an event handler to stop responding to an event, you have to remove the handler.

Comment: hi,
  i have used the unbind thing in my code before that second change...Now when i used my second change ,its working..But if i try to change /using the first change now my first change followed by the second change is also invoked ...But i need only my first to be invoked ...Actually my first change func is to create a field initially ..My second change is to edit the settings of the field already generated..What i m trying now is ..After edit the field settings of any field ...I may create a new field (that is i may create a new field now)...

Comment: It sounds like what you should do is make the change handler a single function, and in that function, decide which action to take based on the conditions. That way, you won't have to unbind anything.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you are not including the same script twice? For example:

Viewstart:

```
Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js
```

Partial view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I got the same problem and I solved it by deleting the min-version.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

I have another case. I got twice send post ajax when bind click a button. It caused by I have two id that has same name, so the trigger detected twice.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project which is using Amazon web service EC2. I am uploading a large file (up to 150 MB). Use Ajax on the front end. And spring MVC on backend. 
My problem is Spring controller "uploadFile()" method called twice. I set a breakpoint in my javascript, javacript method does not called twice.  This only happen on AWS instance, not on my local. And it is around 90 second between uploadFile() method call.
Then the ajax callback  get error. Statuscode= 0, error =""
Firefox Firebug  says "aborted"
Chrome inspect gives me "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

I though it might be some where ajax call backend twice.

I search many solution on stackoverflow. like
1. /add e.preventDefault()  and e.stopImmediatePropagation();
2 ./or change maxSwallowSize in tomcat/confg/server.xml 
3.  $("#uploadFileForm").unbind('submit').submit(function (e) 
4. change async to true and add timeout value to ajax method 
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 60000,
            async: true,

None of above work.

Finaly I soltion it by change idle timeout in ELB to 600 second. And my controller does not called twice.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/

First I want to thanks to all the people who answer question on stackoverflow, which help a lot , a lot, a lot.
The solutions are not wrong , just not to my case. And This issue take me 3 days. I hope it can help you question. 
"ajax fire/ call twice"  "Spring controller call twice"  "Ajax timeout"