# JQuery Ajax method called twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I have this function in a jsp which calls a `struts2` action. But it calls it twice. Why?

`JSP`

```
    $("#inputField").change(function()
    {
        var inputField= $("#inputField").val();
        if(inputField !== '')
        {
            var url = 'myUrl';
            $.getJSON(url, function(retVal)
            {
                $.each(retVal.retList, function(index, element)
                {
                    console.log(element.name);
                });  
            });
        }
    });
```

`Struts2 Action`

```
public String getJSON() throws Exception
{
     System.out.println("Method Executed");
}
```

When this `ajax` call returns, i get this

```
Method Executed
Method Executed
```

How can i make this execute only once?

Comment: is this Jquery function also getting called twice?

Comment: Seems like than the action is also getting called from some where else also.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi The action is not called by any code elsewhere. I have tried returning `return false;` from the `$.getJSON` call, but still the same issue.

Comment: Its only possible in one case when action is getting triggered twice.If you remove the json call what is the bahaviour?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi If i remove the JSON call, it is called once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15901/discussion-between-uchenna-nwanyanwu-and-umesh-awasthi)

Answer (score 1):

You might using JSON plugin and it's calling all your methods that start with "get" in an attempt to serialize them for output.Try to rename your method name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you only register the the 'change' event once. The reason for the double ajax call is probably that you are adding a change listener twice in the code. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950037/same-ajax-called-twice-jquery?rq=1).

Comment: It is only attached once, though the page is reloaded sometimes and i believe all events get unbound when a page reloads using `window.location.replace(url);`. So this means the event is bound only once. Correct me if i am wrong.